# What does Yoshimura mean by "sugar" in chapter 92?

Tags: japanese-language, tokyo-ghoul

On chapter 92, there's a conversation between Yoshimura and Roma inside Anteiku that goes like this:

> Yoshimura: What do you have to be careful about in both "the coffee you served to ghouls" and 'prostitutes on street corner'?
>   Roma: ??
>   Yoshimura: "Sugar"
>   Roma: ...... what? (*confused*)

[image: the conversation inside Anteiku]

This joke went right over my head when I read this chapter. If someone could explain it to me that would be great.

Comment: I want to take a guess as to a prostitute named “Sugar” but I’m not entirely sure if that’s actually the joke

Comment: @AnimNations Is there a character in Tokyo Ghoul named "Satou"? Since that's the Japanese word for "sugar", but can also be used as a name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on [Wikia](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_92), the original joke is about "serving coffee for ghouls" and "man on a (baseball) base". The original script goes like this:

> 「"喰種"へ淹れるコーヒー」とかけて「鈍足な出塁者」ととく――「トウルイは控えるように」。
>
> <sup>[Source (Japanese)](http://yamato676.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-230.html)</sup>

Rough translation:

> "Serving coffee for ghouls" and "slow-footed man on a (baseball) base"... is "to refrain from *tourui*".

Here, *tourui* is either [糖類](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%B3%96%E9%A1%9E) (saccharides; sweeteners) or [盗塁](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%9B%97%E5%A1%81) (base stealing; steal; stolen base), which basically means:

- Not consuming sugar on coffee for ghouls
- Resist stealing a base for slow-footed man

Since this Japanese wordplay is almost impossible to be translated properly (and the joke itself is quite technical), I believe the translator changed it so that joke can be understood easier while trying to preserve the nuance for "sweetener/sugar" and "serving coffee for ghouls".

---

... as for the meaning of "sugar" in the translated version, it probably means:

- Sugar, a prostitute that appears on [*The Crimson Petal and the White*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crimson_Petal_and_the_White) (or alternatively, a general/famous codename used by a prostitute)
- Sugar baby ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_baby))
- Brown sugar, or [heroin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroin)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the sugar is a reference to cocaine. If you look at pictures of crack cocaine, it kind of looks like an off color sugar